# prepare() is undefined

Tags: php, oop, pdo

For the past two days, I have been working on a project, and no matter what I try, I get an error of some sort, or something just doesn't work.  At this point, I am being told that I'm calling an undefined method, upload:prepare(), which is true because the class is called upload, and the statement is $this->prepare()....etc etc.

I am so frustrated that no matter what I do, I cannot figure this out.

**classes.php**

```
<?php
require('config.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
 * Classes required by the script
 * 
 */

class database extends PDO
{
    public $conURL;

    public function __construct($config) {
        $conURL = "mysql:host=" . $config['host'] . ";dbname=" . $config['db'];
        try {
         parent::__construct($conURL, $config['user'], $config['pass']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $e->getMessage();
        }
    }       
}

class upload
{
    public $_FILES;

    public function uploadFile() {
        if ($_FILES['file']['size'] >= 2000000) {
           echo "File is too large!";
        }
        elseif (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
           $stmt = $this->prepare("INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
           $stmt->execute(array($_FILES['file']['name'], $_FILES['file']['type'], $_FILES['file']['size'], $_FILES['file']['file']));
        }
    }
}
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
$config = array(
        'host' => 'localhost', // db host
        'user' => 'root', // db user
        'pass' => 'mypassword', //db pass
        'db' => 'files' // db name
);
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require('config.php');
require('classes.php');

$dbh = new database($config);
$upload = new upload();
$upload->uploadFile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to call the `prepare` function of `upload`, rather than `database`.  Try this:

```
class upload
{
    public $_FILES;

    public function uploadFile($config) {
        $db = new database($config);
        if ($_FILES['file']['size'] >= 2000000) {
           echo "File is too large!";
        }
        elseif (isset($_FILES['file'])) {
           $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO upload (name, type, size, content) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
           $stmt->execute(array($_FILES['file']['name'], $_FILES['file']['type'], $_FILES['file']['size'], $_FILES['file']['file']));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Got a new batch of errors using that: Warning: Missing argument 1 for database::__construct(), called in htdocs/files/classes.php on line 28 and defined in htdocs/files/classes.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined variable: config in htdocs/files/classes.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined variable: config in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/classes.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined variable: config in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/classes.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: file in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/files/classes.php on line 34

Comment: fixed.  I missed the argument for the `database` constructor.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  I still get two issues, both of which shouldn't be occurring.  It says that $config is undefined, which it's not, it's defined in config.php, and that the index "file," is also undefined, which it's not, because I am using the HTML form to pass the data.

Comment: Honestly, that's outside the scope of this question.  I'd post a new question with the relevant HTML.  Don't forget to upvote/accept!

Comment: I'll accept in 56 seconds. ;)  The help is much appreciated, and I'll post the HTML in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to use `database->prepare` instead of `this->prepare` ?

You need to get your upload class an instance of database (or create it on the fly).

Comment: Well I know that $this isn't correct, but if I invoke prepare() from the database class, then I am told that I can't call prepare() statically.

Comment: You need an instance of the database class to call prepare on.